# Automate update process of app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

Is it possible to automate the update process of an app in apples app store?
Say I have 50 Apps and do not want to update them all by myself.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update process is manual, so either you can update your app or can hire someone who can do that for you.

Comment: As i understand you want to update your app automatically without adding new version at ituneconnect and its build matadata then its not possible.

Comment: Have you given a look at itmstransporter? Maybe it's what you're looking for... It may help, at the least.